# Pretty simple recursion for the A290383

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, partitions, recurrences

- Let $a(n)$ be [A290383](https://oeis.org/A290383) i.e. number of set partitions of $[n]$ such that the smallest element of each block is odd. Here
  $$
  a(n)=b(n,0,0)
  $$
  where
  $$
  b(n,m,t)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m-t+1}b(n-1,\max(m,j),1-t), \\
  b(0,m,t)=1
  $$
- Let
  $$
  R_1(n,q)=(q+1)^2R_1(n-1,q)+(q+1)R_1(n-1,q+1), \\
  R_1(0,q)=1
  $$
- Let
  $$
  R_2(n,q)=(q+1)^2R_2(n-1,q)+(q+2)R_2(n-1,q+1), \\
  R_2(0,q)=1
  $$

I conjecture that
$$
R_1(n,0)=a(2n+1), \\
R_2(n,0)=a(2(n+1)).
$$

Is there a way to prove it?